# How to display/hide reference term field on node add

Tags: taxonomy-terms, organic-groups

I have a groupcontent type 'post' that can be posted in two grouptypes 'A'and 'B'

My groupcontenttype 'post'has two vocabularies:

One when posted in grouptype 'A' Vocabulary: practice
One when posted in grouptype 'B' Vocabulary: theory

With a hook_form_alter i like to hide/display my reference term fields based on when my og_group_ref points to grouptype A or B.

Help appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried the [OG Vocabulary](https://www.drupal.org/project/og_vocab) module?

Comment: Or you could use the module Field Conditional State https://www.drupal.org/project/field_conditional_state